# Merge rows within a group together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas DataFrame where some pairs of rows have the same ID but different name.  What I want is to reduce the rows to one row per ID and display both of their names.

INPUT:

```
ID   NAME     AGE
149  Bob      32
150  Tom      53
150  Roberts  53
151  Pamela   28
152  Andrew   23
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID   NAME        AGE
149  Bob         32
150  Tom Roberts 53
151  Pamela      58
152  Andrew      23
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Easily done with `groupby`.

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg({'NAME' : ' '.join, 'AGE' : 'first'})  

ID          NAME  AGE
149          Bob   32
150  Tom Roberts   53
151       Pamela   28
152       Andrew   23
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, what if I only want to aggregate the name, as opposed to another column (updated question)?

Comment: @Landmaster Sorry, you can use `df[['ID', 'NAME']].groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(' '.join)` it's very similar.

Comment: @COLDSPEED how would you assign it to the original frame such that your output is as described above? Right now, it's not giving me the age column.

Comment: Seriously, I can't come up with an alternative that is even close to this good.