# Concatenate cells with duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to concatenate the information (separated by commas) of rows based on a single column duplicate value, and remove all the rest of the duplicates based on that column.

**What I have:**

```
​[in]

pipeline = {'Name':['Josh','Angel','Karina','Josh','Peter','Karina','Karina'],
           'Quote':['9001','9002','9003','9004','9005','9006','9007']}
​
df = pd.DataFrame(pipeline)

[out]​

Name    Quote
0   Josh    9001
1   Angel   9002
2   Karina  9003
3   Josh    9004
4   Peter   9005
5   Karina  9006
6   Karina  9007
```

**What I want:**

```
Name    Quote
0   Josh    9001, 9004
1   Angel   9002
2   Karina  9003, 9006, 9007
4   Peter   9005
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge rows within a group together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636080/merge-rows-within-a-group-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine to list use,

```
df.groupby("Name")['Quote'].apply(list).reset_index()

     Name               Quote
0   Angel              [9002]
1    Josh        [9001, 9004]
2  Karina  [9003, 9006, 9007]
3   Peter              [9005]
```

If you want to join as string use,

```
df.groupby("Name")['Quote'].apply(", ".join).reset_index()

     Name             Quote
0   Angel              9002
1    Josh        9001, 9004
2  Karina  9003, 9006, 9007
3   Peter              9005
```