# Python Pandas extract duplicates from a csv and aggregate the values ​of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file consisting of 4 columns A, B, C, D. I would like to:

- find all duplicates that have the same value for columns A, B, C
- for these take the value of D and create a single row without duplicates, where column D is the union of column D of all duplicates

Example CSV input:

```
John,Yes,123,street 1
John,Yes,123,street 2
Tom,No,345,street 1
Tom,No,345,street 2
Tom,No,345,street 3
Jason,Yes,567,street 1
Thomas,No,123,street 1
Jess,No,999,street 1
```

Expected result:

```
John,Yes,123,street 1 street 2
Tom,No,345,street 1 street 2 street 3
Jason,Yes,567,street 1
Thomas,No,123,street 1
Jess,No,999,street 1
```

Comment: Please add an example or code you've written so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: When you say *create a single row  where column D is the union of column D of all duplicates"*, that could mean Python list, string concatenation, set, dict, etc. Seems like you want "string concatenation".

Comment: You ened to post your own code attempt. In any case this question has many existing duplicates e.g. [Concatenate cells with duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278205/concatenate-cells-with-duplicate-rows). See also the [440 hits for *\[pandas] duplicate concatenate\]*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+duplicate+concatenate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()`

Full code:

```
from io import StringIO
df = """A,B,C,D
John,Yes,123,street 1
John,Yes,123,street 2
Tom,No,345,street 1
Tom,No,345,street 2
Tom,No,345,street 3
Jason,Yes,567,street 1
Thomas,No,123,street 1
Jess,No,999,street 1"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df))
df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jason | Yes | 567 | street 1 |
| 1 | Jess | No | 999 | street 1 |
| 2 | John | Yes | 123 | street 1 street 2 |
| 3 | Thomas | No | 123 | street 1 |
| 4 | Tom | No | 345 | street 1 street 2 street 3 |

Explanation:

`df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()` is the same as
`df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].apply(lambda g: ' '.join(g.values)).reset_index()`
which is the same as these alternatives:

```
# alternative #1
df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['D'].apply(lambda g: ' '.join(g)).reset_index()
# alternative #2
df.groupby(['A','B','C']).apply(lambda g: ' '.join(g['D'])).reset_index()
```