# How can merge the rows by group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group those such that NaN values can be filled and each name appears one time:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df.set_index(['NodeId','Nr_Row']).groupby(['Freq'])['value'].get_group(key) for key in freq_number], axis=1)
df2.columns=freq_number
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.drop('Nr_Row', axis =1, inplace=True)
df2



 NodeId          1800   800 2600    2100
0   AGIKONSFZ-L  1800   NaN NaN     NaN
1   ALLAMBREZ-LTE NaN   800 NaN     NaN
2   ALLIAS-LTE   NaN    NaN 2600    NaN
3   ALLIAS-LTE   1800   NaN NaN     NaN
4   ALLIAS-LTE   NaN    800 NaN     NaN
... ... ... ... ... ...
```

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636080/merge-rows-within-a-group-together)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
df2.groupby('NodeId', as_index=False).agg({'...' : '...'})
```